In Windbg using sosex, !dlk outputs "Failed to load App Domain data for the shared AppDomain. Error = 0x80070057"
I am new to windbg and I have the task of debugging a memory dump, currently the main suspects are thread starvation and deadlocks.
The process (and dump) use .net core 6.0.20, I have both sos and sosex, I load sosex:
.load C:\windbg.extensions\sosex

and after that I run !dlk, howeve this results in the following output:
Examining SyncBlocks...
Failed to load App Domain data for the shared AppDomain. Error = 0x80070057
Scanning for ReaderWriterLock(Slim) instances...
Scanning for holders of ReaderWriterLock locks...
Failed to load App Domain data for the shared AppDomain. Error = 0x80070057
Scanning for holders of ReaderWriterLockSlim locks...
Examining CriticalSections...
No deadlocks detected.

Even though it says "No deadlocks detected", I am still skeptical because of those two rows:
Failed to load App Domain data for the shared AppDomain. Error = 0x80070057
Failed to load App Domain data for the shared AppDomain. Error = 0x80070057

I also have no idea what causes the !dlk command to fault. I have download the .net core 6.0.20 sdk, since I am currently using .net 8 for my new apps, loading using .load coreclr sos loads the sos from my .net8, so I have moved the sos.dll to the C:\windbg.extensions\ and load it using .load C:\windbg.extensions\sos
Other commands like !syncblk, !tp, !runaway work, but I assume it is because they are not part of sosex. Sometimes I had a problem with them, though.
!locks results in Scanned 27 critical sections
I am kind of at a loss, and I really don't know how to fix the two failing rows in !dlk, when I read about the exception code, none were related to my case, I believe the users had problems loading other things, but I didn't quite understand the proposed solutions.

Extensions for .NET Framework are not applicable to .NET Core in general. If you don’t know how to use alternatives, you might hire an experienced consultant or open a support case via https://support.microsoft.com. This isn’t something trivial and not possible to be taught over a site like this.
